# Is there any way to automatically generate java classes from Neo4j graph database

Tags: java, spring-boot, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, neo4j-ogm

In my application, we choosen Neo4j as database. We have designed the database with all the required nodes and relationships. We are trying to integrate the in our springboot java program with reactive neo4j repository. Now we are planning to create equivalent entities.

Is there any way to automatically generate java classes from Neo4j graph database which will be equivalent to @Node and @RelationshipProperties used entities as we create manually.

Comment: Can someone help me on this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no tool for this and this is in general a good thing when it comes to "complex" data in the graph.

Spring Data Neo4j (6) does only fetch the relationships and properties of a node that you define in your model.
If you would map your graph 1:1 you might end up with ones you do not need. They will pollute your code base and create unnecessary long Cypher statements / data transfers.

I would say that there is -in contrast to the usage of RDBMS- a lot of "shared database" usage in the graph world.
The partial match of a domain model in the application to the graph model is no exception here.

Also a tool that blindly converts your data into a model can only make assumptions.
E.g. multiple labels: You can define them in multiple ways depending on your use-case in Spring Data Neo4j.
But which one is the right one for the tool?
This can produce code that is not your desired outcome and you would have to manually refactor it after creation.
Imagine having such a tool in a build chain: You would have to manually fine-tune the resulting model over and over again.